# There is a way to abstract the creating of types and/or mutations in GraphQl using just the model file of mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, graphql

I would like to create a way that with just the models of mongoose, the GraphQl generates the right type and mutations. It is possible to do this?

I'm searching for a solution but I have found nothing until now.

Is that because it is not possible to do this?

Comment: Not using models, but something similar to `Prisma` could possibly do what you need - https://www.prisma.io

Comment: Wow! Prisma is what I need! Is there a downside to use? Perfomance issues? The prisma generates the files just when compile?

Comment: There is a boilerplate with apollo and graphql?

Comment: I'm going to recommend closing this question because any answer to it is pretty much going to be "just use X", which is opinion-based and so not really on topic for SO. That said, a [quick search](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=graphql%20mongoose) will point you to any number of libraries.

Comment: @DaniloCunha not sure what you mean by "performance issues" - it's just a GraphQL server, so the performance will be just like any other GraphQL sever. I am not sure if `Prisma` will work with `Apollo` - those are two "competing" technologies. But give it a try, and see if it suits your needs.